# import .csv avoiding conversion to double data in R

Tags: r

I have a problem using the `descdist()` function of the `fitdistrplus` package on my data frame. I think the problem comes from the data type: double. I would like to avoid the conversion to double when importing my csv, but keeping the data as a numeric (I apparently cannot convert them back using as.numeric, it remains as double after that).

Here is my code to import the dataset:

```
setwd("[directory]")
data=read.csv('data_BehCoor.csv', header=T, sep=";", dec=".", fill=T)

require("fitdistrplus")
descdist(data$stateTSp)
```

returns the following error

```
Error in plot.window(...) : 'xlim' needs finite values
```

An idea of the data:

```
dput(head(data))
structure(list(day = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
trial = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), ID = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), 
.Label = c("", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"),
 class = "factor"), 
condition = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
"C", "T"), class = "factor"), gender = structure(c(3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("", "F", "M"), class = "factor"), 
TSp = c(5, 3, 1, 5, 0, 6), AGR = c(3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), beAGR = c(0, 
3, 0, 0, 0, 0), FOR = c(27.729, 24.51, 51.459, 37.645, 34.489, 
34.281), FOR_noTSp = c(22.729, 21.51, 50.459, 32.645, 34.489, 
28.281), NI = c(39.857, 82.421, 76.922, 9.277, 265.484, 249.692
), stateTSp = c(55.858, 21.607, 0, 79.961, 0, 2.001), TSpFOR = c(20.345, 
8.408, 0, 0, 0, 0), tot_duration = c(136.967, 136.967, 128.395, 
128.395, 300, 300), OL_FOR = c(3.746, 3.746, 5.002, 5.002, 
10.081, 10.081), OL_FOR_stateTSp = c(4.563, 10.907, 41.703, 
0, 0, 0), OL_FOR_TSpFOR = c(3.372, 1.113, 0, 0, 0, 0), OL_FOR_NI = c(11.041, 
8.496, 2.748, 27.639, 19.655, 18.191), OL_stateTSp_FOR = c(10.907, 
4.563, 0, 41.703, 0, 0), OL_stateTSp = c(3.249, 3.249, 0, 
0, 0, 0), OL_stateTSp_TSpFOR = c(4.034, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
OL_stateTSp_NI = c(36.66, 
11.79, 0, 37.249, 0, 2.001), OL_TSpFOR_FOR = c(1.113, 3.372, 
0, 0, 0, 0), OL_TSpFOR_stateTSp = c(0, 4.034, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
OL_TSpFOR = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OL_TSpFOR_NI = c(18.23, 
2.499, 0, 0, 0, 0), overlap_NI_FOR = c(8.496, 11.041, 27.639, 
2.748, 18.191, 19.655), OL_NI_stateTSp = c(11.79, 36.66, 
37.249, 0, 2.001, 0), OL_NI_TSpFOR = c(2.499, 18.23, 0, 0, 
0, 0), OL_NI = c(16.065, 16.065, 6.528, 6.528, 230.021, 230.021
), AGR_in_FOR = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), AGR_in_stateTSp = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), AGR_in_TSpFOR = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), AGR_in_NI = c(3, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), beAGR_in_FOR = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), beAGR_in_stateTSp = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), beAGR_in_TSpFOR = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), beAGR_in_NI = c(0, 
3, 0, 0, 0, 0), comment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), 
.Label = c("", "moved the plate too fast"), class = "factor")),
 row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm afraid that the information you have provided will make it difficult for the community to help you. Can you provide more information about your data, how you are using the function and the error that is thrown out? I would suggest you to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: yes I tried to add part of my dataset as an example but cannot find how to join it.. ^^'

Comment: Have a look at the link in the first comment. Sometimes copying the results of `dput(head(data))`  in the question might be enough.

Comment: from your example `plot(df$stateTSp)` work fine. I'm pretty sure that the problem is not the double type. You probably have some `NA`, of `Inf` values in `df$stateTsp`.

Comment: it imported a last line full of NAs.. now it is good, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

`fitdistrplus::descdist` works fine with type `double`, see below:

```
foo <- runif(50, min = 1, max = 100)
typeof(foo)
fitdistrplus::descdist(foo)
```